# How do I deal with a number of different types of valueError results in Python / Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, try-except, valueerror

I am trying to extract a value from an input that is `dirty` with a number of possibilities.

The input is a Series that has a number of possible types for example: `"8673331000", "8673331000'", 8673331000, 18673331000, 8673331000.0, NaN, "867B331000"`

In the first 5 cases, I am looking for `867333`, in `int` format. The last two cases I would like to report `Unknown` or something to that effect.

I've been using try / except, however there are a number of different types of `ValueError` reported.

Right now I am using:

```
*try:
    val = int(number)
except ValueError as ve:
    if (number[len(number)-1]=="'"):
        val = int(number[0:len(number)-2])
    else:
        val = int(float(number))*
```

This `except` clause handles the case where the input has a single quotation mark but does not handle the `NaN` case.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Are you saying you would like to add another `except` clause for a different exception? You can do that just by adding another `except` clause just like the `ValueError` one.

Comment: Or you can add an `else` clause to the `try` stmt, see [here](http://amir.rachum.com/blog/2012/07/24/what-else-is-there-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

If the input is already a pandas Series, you can use `pandas.to_numeric(your_series_data, errors='coerce').fillna(-9999).astype(int)`

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# some example data
data=StringIO('''Values
,8673331000
,8673331000
,8673331000
,18673331000
,8673331000.0
,NaN
,867B331000
''')

#read data to csv
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",")

# your data may already be a pandas series, which below is df.iloc[:,0]
pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:,0],errors='coerce').fillna(-9999).astype(int)

NaN     8673331000 
NaN     8673331000
NaN     8673331000
NaN    18673331000
NaN     8673331000
NaN          -9999
NaN          -9999
Name: Values, dtype: int64
```

You can use the values of this series directly, without having to use try/except to coerce them to integers.

Integers can't be represented as NaN in pandas, so in the example they are replaced with -9999. when you are extracting values from the Series, if it matches -9999, you can set it to None or whatever value your code should have for a missing value.

If your input values are strings they may get coerced to NaN instead of to integers, e.g.

```
data=StringIO('''Values
,8673331000
,"8673331000"
,\'8673331000\'
,18673331000
,8673331000.0
,NaN
,867B331000
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",")
```

The 3rd value will end up as NaN when using `pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:,0], errors='coerce').fillna(-9999).astype(int)` In this case I would suggest just removing all " or ' from your input data

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I settled on an elaborate if/elif clause with regex. I suspect a nested try/except would work however given that a valueError can result from a number of different possibilities, I am sticking with the former.

Here is what I landed on, with some edits for simplicity

def get_code(input, logger):
    # grabs the integer form of a raw input that can come in the form of 
    # an int, float, string (e.g. 8673341000, 18673341000, "8673341000",
    # "8673341000'", "  8673341000  ", "867BBA1000", 8673341000.0, NaN
    # returns "Unknown" if illegible input provided

```
import re
import math
import numpy as np

val = "Unknown"

if (type(input)==int):
    val = input

elif(type(input)==float):
    #could be NaN or a float (e.g. 100.0, but not 1.0e+10)
    try:
        val= int(input)
    except:
        val="Unknown"

elif(type(input)==str):
    if (input[len(input)-1]=="'"):
        val = int(input[0:len(input)-1])
    elif (re.match('^[0-9]+$', input)):
        #input contains only digits
        val = int(input)
    elif ((re.match('\s+\d+\s+', input)) or (re.match('\s+\d+', input)) or (re.match('\d+\s+', input))):
        #leading or trailing spaces
        input = input.strip()
        val=int(input)
    else:
        return "Unknown"
elif(type(np.float64(input).item())==float):
    #Input is of the form 1.416441e+10

    val = int(input)


else:
    logger.warning("Unknown Input type for get_NPANXX() ... input:" , input)
    logger.warning(type(input))
    return val #E.g. "Unknown Input"

#...more processing once val is in integer form
return
```